# Change camera dynamically in A-Frame

Tags: aframe

I'm trying something may be insane. Idea is, on mouse hover on a sphere, change the stereo camera with an image. The default camera will be the stereo camera, so on mouseleave all I have to do is set the main camera active and turn off the secondary camera. Is it possible to set the camera on run time? Any help? Thanks in advance.

```
    <a-assets>
        <img id="image1" src="image1.png"/>
        <img id="image2" src="image2.jpg"/>
    </a-assets>
    <a-camera >
        <a-image position="0 0 -1" width="0.2" height="0.2" src="#image1">
    </a-camera>

    <a-camera stereocam position="-47 0 -35" >
        <a-cursor fuse="true" color="black" position="0 0 -1" timeout="500" src="#warning">
        </a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the active camera.

```
document.querySelector('#camera2').setAttribute('camera', 'active', true);
```

Comment: Great, works just the way I wanted. Could you please tell where to find the complete description of properties of `a-camera` (other a-frame objects as well)? The a-frame site has abridged version, which is not much helpful for novice like me, since I don't have much experience in jscript.